# How do you group tables in ClickHouse similar to a SQL Server schema?

Tags: clickhouse

I am giving ClickHouse a try as a possible implementation (moving away from SQL Server for OLAP queries and trying different columnar store DBMS's) and wondering if there's a way to group tables (and other objects) similar to the SQL Server schema concept. Short of creating different db's, how do I achieve this in ClickHouse?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a database in ClickHouse is almost no overhead - think of it as a namespace. (Databases do have engines, and you use `Atomic` in most cases).

So you would just create a database for each of your SQL Server schemas.

Comment: So if I want to sort of replicate my SQL Server implementation where I have a single db with around 10 different schemas to group/organize tables being ingested from different sources, the equivalent in ClickHouse would be to create 10 databases? 10 different maintenance plans or whatever this is called in the CH world? I am referring to scheduled backups, etc.

Comment: Without the presence of schemas, this is indeed your best option.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback!